# Get Top Level Synsets in WordNet JWNL

Tags: java, wordnet

I want to get the top level noun synsets in English wordnet using JWNL library. As I know there are 25 synsets at the top level. Can somebody help me to find a way to do it please.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to do this using JAWS library. Try searching for that.